# Should we enable azure application insights profiler in production?

Tags: azure-application-insights-profiler

Is it a good idea to enable application insights profiler in production azure web app all the time ?
Or should we enable only when we have any performance issues ?

I tried to enable it in production , but do not know weather keeping profiler on will have any -ve impact on application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [..] but do not know weather keeping profiler on will have any -ve impact on application

It does, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/profiler/profiler-overview#overhead-and-sampling-algorithm):

*When Profiler is running, it adds from 5 percent to 15 percent CPU overhead to the server.*

It is up to you to decide whether this is acceptable or not.

I wouldn't personally run it always. Only when there are performance issues. You might one to run in once in a while to check proactive for issues before those issues become a real problem.